# Querying nested data in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to extract all columns in bigquery google analytics data   WHERE I filtered by hostname.
However, the result is still showing the other hostnames as seen on screenshot. 
I'm doing this select with a filter to copy data to another dataset with the same schema. [image]

QUERY BELOW:

```
SELECT g.* FROM `10241241.ga_sessions_20160805` g, UNNEST (hits) as hits WHERE hits.page.hostname= "www.googlemerchandisestore.com"
```

**UPDATED**
How can I copy the same schema without changing its nested structure?

[image: error in nested schema]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values you want to filter for are sitting in an array ... so you can filter/clean the array or exclude rows with arrays not containing that value or exclude rows that contain not only that value. Not sure which applies for you, since you don't seem to have a reason to cross join the array with the whole table (which bloats it up tremendously).

Cleaning the array:

```sql
SELECT 
  * 
  REPLACE( 
    ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT * FROM g.hits WHERE page.hostname='www.googlemerchandisestore.com') AS hits
    ) 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20160805` g
limit 1000
```

Exclude rows that don't contain the value

```sql
SELECT 
  * 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20160805` g
WHERE
  (SELECT COUNT(1)>0 FROM g.hits WHERE page.hostname='www.googlemerchandisestore.com')
limit 1000
```

etc.

Comment: It does work! I used the first one since I need all columns to be added to the new table. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add hits column again. Also, I'd recommend you to use a different name for unnested column. It'll be easier to understand, then.

```
SELECT g.* EXCEPT(hits), hit 
FROM `10241241.ga_sessions_20160805` g, UNNEST (hits) as hit 
WHERE hits.page.hostname= "www.googlemerchandisestore.com"
```

Comment: it worked, however, in the copied destination the hits became hit, and also changed the schema. It seems it is not recognize as nested anymore. How do I make it the same was I copied from the source table? Attached screenshot